# My encryption/decryption solution not working properly

Tags: php, mcrypt

I am attempting to figure out what is wrong with my encryption/decryption code but I seem to be hitting a dead end in my Google searching for issues similar to mine.

Here is my php code for the two functions but I will explain first.  How these work is by using a salt, the user's password, and the unix epoch time that they last logged in (or the current epoch time if they have never logged in before) to create the encrypted password.

Right now I am testing out the code to see if it works or not before hooking it into the rest of my php code.  The password being passed to the function is Test and it is using time() to supply the time and then storing that value during the encryption process to a global variable so I do not have to store it into the database while testing.

In one SO thread, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229136/php-decrypt-not-working-using-mcrypt-decrypt), I read that using MCRYPT_RAND when creating the IV and then not saving that produced IV meant that decrypt would never work because the IV would be different if you re-called mcrypt_create_iv to create the IV during the decryption.  So I made a global for the IV as well and tried that in the decryption process but it still does not decrypt properly.  The code below reflects that change.

```
  //Encrypt the user's password for storing in database 
function encrypt($password, $id)
{
    echo "Function: encrypt \n"; //For debugging

    $salt2 = getTime($id);

    $salt1 = 'akey'; //Changed for security purposes

    global $cur_iv;

    $key = substr(hash('sha256',$salt1.$password.$salt2),0,32);
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size,MCRYPT_RAND);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $password, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));

    $cur_iv = $iv;

    echo $encrypted;
    echo "\n";

    global $cur_time;

    $cur_time = $salt2; 

    return $encrypted;
}

//Decrypt the user's password for loggin checking
function decrypt($password,$id)
{
    echo "Function: decrypt \n"; //For debugging

    //$salt2 = getTime($id);
    global $cur_time;
    $salt2 = $cur_time;

    $salt1 = 'akey'; //Changed for security purposes

    global $cur_iv;

    $key = substr(hash('sha256',$salt1.$password.$salt2),0,32);
    $iv = $cur_iv;
    $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($pass), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);

    echo $decrypted;
    echo "\n";

    return $decrypted;
}
```

Encrypted this is what the password looks like: xgr5YB0vHwJAkjkqwTl6rnZMjbZL0qmLE4D8JXDT1rM=

But decrypted it looks like this: NÞÚ±=º)cz_öUñŽP´è8Åáó»d—+ÒAÐ

Edit 2:

Here is the getTime function as requested by Saikios:

```
//Use the last login time for part of the encryption salt to ensure more secure hashing
function getTime($id)
{
    global $sql;

    echo "Function: getTime \n"; //For debugging

    if ($salt_stmt = $sql->prepare("Select Last_Login From login_log Where User_ID = ?;"))
    {
        $salt_stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
        $salt_stmt->execute();
        $salt_stmt->store_result();
        $salt_stmt->bind_result($time);
        $salt_stmt->fetch();

        if ($salt_stmt->num_rows < 1)
        {
            echo "No last login \n";

            $time = time();
        }

        else
        {   
            echo "Last Login Time: ".$time."\n";            
        }

        return $time;

    }

    else
    {
        echo "Error: ".$sql->error; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`?

Comment: Or just encript the password input from the user and compare it with the one on database?

Comment: in the decrypt function you also have: `$salt2 == $cur_time;` so you are comparing the two instead of setting.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn *facepalm* thanks for pointing that out, I will fix that right now.  Edit: still not working.

Comment: @GergoErdosi & Jorge Campos It was a requirement from my employer, site and by extension php code has to meet HIPPA requirements.  As for not just check against the database, the login time part of the key will change over time on each successful login and the password will be re-encrypted at that time.  Eventually I may move to that method of checking against the database but for testing I want make sure I can decrypt the passwords in case I need it for something later on.

Comment: @Geowil: "in case I need it for something later on" --- or in case someone who has (malicious) access to your database needs it for something.

Comment: @zerkms Which is one reason why I may not use it once the code is out of testing stages.

Comment: @Geowil: I honestly cannot get why to even spend time on something that shouldn't be done by design at first place.

Comment: I would suggest using asymmetric encryption for this.  That way you can keep one key safe at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use mine, but please don't use md5('password') as your key :)

```
function symEncode($decrypted, $key){
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);

        $iv_base64 = rtrim(base64_encode($iv), '=');
        // Encrypt $decrypted and an MD5 of $decrypted using $key.  MD5 is fine to use here because it's just to verify successful decryption.
        $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $decrypted . md5($decrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
        // We're done!
        return $iv_base64 . $encrypted;
    }

function symDecode($encrypted, $key){
    // Retrieve $iv which is the first 43 characters plus ==, base64_decoded.
    $iv = base64_decode(substr($encrypted, 0, 43) . '==');
    // Remove $iv from $encrypted.
    $encrypted = substr($encrypted, 43);
    // Decrypt the data.  rtrim won't corrupt the data because the last 32 characters are the md5 hash; thus any \0 character has to be padding.
    //pre_var_export(debug_backtrace(false));
    $decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv), "\0\4");
    // Retrieve $hash which is the last 32 characters of $decrypted.
    $hash = substr($decrypted, -32);
    // Remove the last 32 characters from $decrypted.
    $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -32);
    // Integrity check.  If this fails, either the data is corrupted, or the password/salt was incorrect.
    if (md5($decrypted) != $hash){
        die('failed');
    }
    // Yay!
    return $decrypted;
}


$key = md5('password');
$decrypted = 'some important data';

$encrypted = symEncode($decrypted, $key);
echo $encrypted . '<br>';  
echo symDecode($encrypted, $key);
```

Outputs:

```
43p2K/0RG20fnuHEx2B3q18KM7FpGLRfb+BwFfYt1V1mMr5PsAroum/jEeO6LonmC4T9N6QQQfOfMwTmbyNRFG4Qi5imGPAq0LsbgYJHWZ50Lw0C7uSRDb7CC1I4Uv1/LFQ==

some important data
```

And

```
$key = md5('password');
        $decrypted = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc bibendum augue et vehicula adipiscing. Maecenas interdum, enim a accumsan convallis, est urna posuere mauris, eu ultricies lacus enim at justo. Vestibulum auctor sed elit a';
```

Outputs:

```
431nn42sTg7/XlGw4nAw3aFmMiYOnOQCVMjs4xY2m3DNcgiTFyqs1scG3VCxx/srEV9OGePqD4qrV1AectSqIWCSjYCinsS1jThEL9OuxxXeaGCbycXybdeMUCz1gKJZ5zVegMjqcWzyaX6/32sMs+Mh/NO+e9uh9lOdgmpofHEUWc9m4n6yziX2TllDKxbbADogeRjfW5SzzhaR/bx24kV9/44QhMRA1IJwFteHzCI9qTLGL/586MziGUVbZJe9Y9TqhiWEAIgJ0tO0iWVGMBYV1ibwv8VzDr0LcN7qL4345ryoQ3hjrixpLnBNKewKhbCB/4EkJ7+FD1nUyHOZLEyhi52oMqs/uDv1qSk/Pgk+Poku8DCd5ZbxbAJQG6Wp8BlZzfXOak1tyTKaJUsRziM/zmaXvpYrq3WWJti4cQaxc

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc bibendum augue et vehicula adipiscing. Maecenas interdum, enim a accumsan convallis, est urna posuere mauris, eu ultricies lacus enim at justo. Vestibulum auctor sed elit a
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to fashion something out of this and give it a whirl.

Comment: What are you encrypting there are different uses for different encryption,  The flaw with any symmetric 2 way encryption is always have to have the same key.

Comment: Also this is some modified and updated code i found a while back, and while I like to think I'm pretty good at this, I don't know if id use it for the missile codes if you know what I mean, lol

Answer (score 1):

I know you want to use your own function, but why don't you use this as a base (by Naveen S. Nayak, who is not me http://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/simple-php-encrypt-and-decrypt/),

```
function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string) {
    $output = false;

    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key = 'This is my secret key';
    $secret_iv = 'This is my secret iv';

    // hash
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

    // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

    if( $action == 'encrypt' ) {
        $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
        $output = base64_encode($output);
    }
    else if( $action == 'decrypt' ){
        $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    }

    return $output;
}

$plain_txt = "This is my plain text";
echo "Plain Text = $plain_txt\n";

$encrypted_txt = encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $plain_txt);
echo "Encrypted Text = $encrypted_txt\n";

$decrypted_txt = encrypt_decrypt('decrypt', $encrypted_txt);
echo "Decrypted Text = $decrypted_txt\n";

if( $plain_txt === $decrypted_txt ) echo "SUCCESS";
else echo "FAILED";

echo "\n";
```

(there seems to be a problem on how you are passing the variables)

-----OLD----------
I don't have the function getTime but ....

On encrypt change

```
$cur_time = salt2;
```

for

```
$cur_time = $salt2;
```

Comment: I will add it to the OP but fixing the few issues with the code did not resolve the original problem.

Comment: @Geowil, [OP](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op) means you.

Comment: @sectus I thought TC was Topic Creator while OP was Original Post?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the blog, I will also check out this and see what I can do with it; maybe combine the two methods proposed by both yourself and ArtisticPhoenix.